# npm test for compoundjs application

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, nodeunit, compoundjs

I have a compound js application. I only generated scaffold using

compound g scaffold user name surname

This command also created test/controllers/users-controllers-test.js file.
I have tried ruuning this test as "npm test".

But on windows, it gave error as "`Error: ENOENT, stat '.........\test\*\*`'

And on linux/centos, it gave an error like "ReferenceError: describe is not defined"

Please help me out to understand what exactly I am missing...

Please need an aswer asap as it stucks my work.

Thanks in advance,
Waiting for positive answers,

Thanks

Comment: You have a webserver running on the same port? Or maybe Skype (port 80)

Comment: No I am running my node application on port 3000... when I run the app, it runs and works fine But "npm test" doesn't work Please guide.

Comment: `$ npm test`? What you want to acchieve? `$ npm install test`? https://npmjs.org/package/test

Comment: I need to run the tests that are generated using "compound g scaffold"..in the folder test/controllers/....

Comment: You sure you don't want `$ node test` to run your app?

Comment: Please clarify me... to run the unit tests we use "npm test" command correct?

Comment: Also, running "node test" command gives me this error "Error: Cannot find module '/opt/testApp/test'".... Please help me understand..

Comment: No, npm = [Node Packaged Modules](https://npmjs.org/). Here you can download modules for node. To run your app, you need `$ node <appname>`

Comment: ok... understood..then what is the command I can use to run my unit test cases

Comment: Depends on your test. You could [look here for the docs](https://github.com/1602/compound)

Comment: For anyone reading this thread: `npm test` is often the prescribed way to test a node module. But this only works if a proper `test` script is specified in the module's `package.json` file. Here, probably a faulty test script is specified, so the `npm test` command does not work. See [documentation for package.json 'scripts' field](https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html).

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639709/448876.

You should use `mocha test/*` instead of `npm test`.

First make sure mocha is installed:

```
npm install -g mocha
```