# tests in nodejs with compoundjs and mocha

Tags: node.js, nodeunit, compoundjs

I have created from scratch scaffolded compoundjs app using:

```
compound init test_app && cd test_app
```

Than

```
compound g crud user id name password created:date
```

Than

```
npm test
```

which runs: ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --include test/init.js test/*/*.test.js

However, I only get the following output errors:

```
> test_app@0.0.1 test /home/ubuntu/test_app
```

> ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --include test/init.js test/*/*.test.js

```
✖ 1 of 10 tests failed:

1) UserController "before each" hook:
 ReferenceError: getApp is not defined
  at Context.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/test_app/test/controllers/users_controller.test.js:16:11)
  at Hook.Runnable.run (/home/ubuntu/test_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:196:15)
  at next (/home/ubuntu/test_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:243:10)
  at Object._onImmediate (/home/ubuntu/test_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:254:5)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:317:15)


npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using mocha fixed the issue:

```
mocha test/*
```